# Idea Live Template to Log Method Args

Tags: java, ide, intellij-idea

I would like to be able to create a live template in Jetbrain's Idea that will log the method's arguments. Let's call it "larg". It would work like:

```
public void get(String one, String two) {
    larg<tab>
```

to create

```
public void get(String one, String two) {
    log.info("get: one = " + one + " two = " + two);
```

I'm fine with getting the method name in, but have not figured out how to pull in the method arguments. Any ideas?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm 4 years late, but the predefined template soutp pretty much does this using a groovyscript variable.

Here's the groovy script that does what you're looking for

```
groovyScript("'\"' + _1.collect { it + ' = [\" + ' + it + ' + \"]'}.join(', ') + '\"'", methodParameters())
```

Comment: It wasn't clear for me that this worked in java. If you go to [Live Templates] -> [output] -> [soutp] then you will see this script in action and it definitely works. Thanks!

Comment: Does this work for javascript as well? Tried with no luck, maybe I missed something

Comment: Simple, yet related: to access only first, second, third etc.. parameter of _1, simply use `_1[0]`, `_1[1]`, etc.

Comment: Inspired by this answer i created the following live template for parameterized log message which produces LOG.debug("get - one: {}, two: {}", one, two): 
LOG.debug($MSG$); with the following script for the variable MSG:
groovyScript("'\"' + _1 + (!_2.isEmpty() ? ' - ' : '') + _2.collect { it + ': {}'}.join(', ') + '\"' + (!_2.isEmpty() ? ', ' + _2.collect {it}.join(', ') : '')", methodName(), methodParameters())

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is not currently possible with a live template.

From the [Jetbrain's forum](http://www.jetbrains.net/devnet/thread/283758):

```
There is no predefined live template function to do this for you automatically.
You can write a plugin that would provide such a function.
```

Answer (score 0):

this is my groovy script

```
groovyScript("import com.intellij.psi.*;import com.intellij.psi.util.PsiTreeUtil; def file = PsiDocumentManager.getInstance(_editor.project).getPsiFile(_editor.document); PsiMethod method = PsiTreeUtil.findElementOfClassAtOffset(file, _editor.caretModel.offset, PsiMethod.class, false); PsiParameter[] parameters = method == null ? PsiParameter.EMPTY_ARRAY : method.parameterList.parameters; return parameters.size() == 0 ? '' : '\"' + method.name + ' : ' + parameters.collect { def prefix = it.name + ' = '; def type = it.type; return type instanceof PsiArrayType ? type.componentType instanceof PsiPrimitiveType ? prefix + '\" + java.util.Arrays.toString(' + it.name + ')' : prefix + '\" + java.util.Arrays.deepToString(' + it.name + ')' : prefix + '\" + ' + it.name }.join(' + \", ')", methodParameters())
```

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio in Kotlin I use this to log classname, methodname and parameters.
I use my name as tag to easily filter in logcat. I use these mainly for debugging, I don't commit these messages with my name.

`Log.d("MYNAME", "$CLASS_NAME$:$METHOD_NAME$: $PARAMETERS$")`

And then the parameters are defined as follows.

`CLASS_NAME` : `kotlinClassName()`

`METHOD_NAME` : `kotlinFunctionName()`

`PARAMETERS` : `groovyScript("'' + _1.collect { it + ' = $' + it}.join(', ') ", functionParameters())`

This would be the result if used in the main activity

```kotlin
 fun aFunctionWithParameters( first: Int, second: String, third: ArrayList<String>){
        Log.d("MYNAME", "MainActivity:aFunctionWithParameters: first = $first, second = $second, third = $third")
    }
```

I based my solution on Rob's answer and edited it to my needs.

Answer (score 0):

groovyScript("def params = _3.collect {it + ' = " + ' + it + ' + "'}.join(', '); return '"' + _1 + ' :: ' + _2 + '() >>'  + (params.empty  ? '' : ': ' + params)  + '"'",  kotlinClassName() ,  kotlinFunctionName(),  functionParameters())

This will print:

```
Log.d(TAG, "MyClassName :: myMethodName() >>: param1 = " + param1 + ", parma2 = " + parma2 + "");
```

Refer this image on how to add this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHwgl.png