# pycharm (any IntelliJ) functions over variables

Tags: python, intellij-idea, pycharm

I found myself on writing plenty of class `__init__` of this form

```
class Document():
    document_id = None
    repository_id = None
    schema_id = None
    insert_date = None

    def __init__(self, document_id=None, repository_id=None, schema_id=None, insert_date=None):
        self.document_id = document_id
        self.repository_id = repository_id
        self.schema_id = schema_id
        self.insert_date = insert_date
```

so I created a template that is of this form.

```
class $name$():

    def __init__(self, $args$):
```

It solves only partially my problem, since I've to write every time all the init of variable in the `__init__` and also in the `class`

Is is possible to do iteration over args of the live template? Something like:

```
class $name$():
    {% for $arg$ in $args$ %}
    $arg$ 
    {%end for%}
    def __init__(self, $args$):
        {% for $arg$ in $args$ %}
        self.$arg$ = $arg$
        {%end for%}
```

if so how? or how can I easy my life?

Comment: Not that it even *addresses* the question, but: why do you have both class attributes and default parameter values?

Comment: Because the code smart-completion in pycharm seems to catch only the class attributes.

Comment: For IntelliJ one can use `groovyScript` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440525/idea-live-template-to-log-method-args/21168027

Comment: @EsseTi PyCharm supports instance attributes as well. You do not need to copy class and instance attributes. If instance attributes do do work for you, then it is a bug and you need to contact their support

Comment: Ok. But the problem of do the setters in the unit remains. And I'm sure that 99% of inits are as my example